# WCF service method not being called from ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, ajax, wcf

I am trying to call a WCF method on page load from ASP.NET using AJAX. However nothing happens when my page loads even if the code is executed. Also I dont get any errors. Below are the code snippets I wrote. Am I missing anything here?

AJAX Code - The service is configured in IIS properly and .svc is browsing without any errors.

```
<script lang="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost/FinService.svc/GetMessage",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                var value = JSON.stringify(response);
                alert(value);
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

WCF method - interface

```
namespace Fin.ServiceContracts
{
  [ServiceContract]
  public partial interface IFinService
  {
    [OperationContract(Name = "GetMessage")]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string GetMessage();
  }
}
```

WCF method implementation

```
namespace Fin.Service
{
  [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
  public partial class FinService : IFinService
  {
    public string GetMessage()
    {
        return "hi from wcf";
    }
  }
}
```

Web.config

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WebBinding"/>
      </webHttpBinding>
  </bindings>

  <services>
     <service behaviorConfiguration="sbehaviour" name="myservice">
        <endpoint address="" binding ="WebBinding" contract ="Fin.ServiceContracts.IFinService" behaviorConfiguration="WebHttpBidning_IPublicService"/>
     </service>
  </services>

  <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WebHttpBidning_IPublicService">
            <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>

    <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="sbehaviour">
           <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
           <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
   </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: OMG would people STOP using WCF for this sort of stuff. :|

Comment: No errors..  Here is the link which I refer the code example to try:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dacca2/understand-jquey-ajax-function-call-method-in-wcf-service/

Comment: Does your WCF hosted on the same project?. If yes try to remove the `http://localhost/` and see what happens

Comment: Try debuging using your javascript console I believe it s an Access-Control-Allow-Origin problem